# Remove small gap between top of page and Nav

Tags: html, css

I have tried setting margin: 0; and border-box in multiple places even. But i still have a small gap between the nav and top. I was not able to set nav to sticky for some reason, but had to set instead the header to sticky. I posted all the code i think will be needed let me know if you guys need to see even more of it i could possible also upload it to codepen. Thanks in advance!

[image: The gap is at the top between my search bar and the nav/header its a thin line and i can see the background while scrolling]
----Html Code Below----

```
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <!-- Navigation: Mobile -->
            <div class="hamburger">
                <div class="line line-top"></div>
                <div class="line line-middle"></div>
                <div class="line line-bottom"></div>
            </div>
            <img class="logo" src="../icons/SVG/logo.svg" alt="Dopematik Logo">
            <div class="header_functionality">
                <img style="cursor: pointer;" class="searchSvg" src="../icons/SVG/search.svg" alt="Search Button">
                <img style="cursor: pointer;" class="shoppingCartSvg" src="../icons/SVG/shoppingCart.svg"
                    alt="Shopping Cart Button">
            </div>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Navigation: Deskop -->
            <div class="header_table">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About<mark class="dropdown-menu">&#9660;</mark></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Shop<mark class="dropdown-menu">&#9660;</mark></a></li>
                    <li><a class="last_link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

-----CSS Code Below-----

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    background-color: #141414;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    /* 10px */
    /* font-size: calc(1em + 0.5vw); */
}

body,
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* TODO: FIGURE OUT PROBLEM WITH STICKY NAV BAR! */
/* Navigation Section*/
header {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    top: 0;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 1000;
}

nav {
    background-color: #141414;
    opacity: 0.98;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Hamburger- Mobile Devices */
.line {
    width: 62px;
    height: 11px;
    background: #D4AF37;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
}

/* Hamburger- Top Line */
.line-top {
    top: 28px;
    left: 41px;
}

/* Hamburger- Middle Line */
.line-middle {
    top: 48px;
    left: 41px;
}

/* Hamburger- Bottom Line */
.line-bottom {
    top: 68px;
    left: 41px;
}

/* Dopematik Logo */
.logo {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Header Functionality (Search & Cart SVG) */
.header_functionality {
    text-align: right;
    width: 95vw;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: -60px;
}

/* Shopping Cart SVG */
.shoppingCartSvg {
    padding-left: 35px;
}

/* Navigation Links: Mobile*/
.nav-links {
    border: 2px solid green;
    text-align: center;
    height: 85vh;
}

.nav-links li {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

.nav-links a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #CDB04E;
    font-size: 6rem;
}

.nav-links a:hover {
    color: whitesmoke;
}

/* Navigation Links: Desktop */
.header_table {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.header_table ul {
    font-size: 3.2rem;
    list-style: none;
}

.header_table li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.header_table li a {
    font-family: 'Arapey';
    color: #D4AF37;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 5px 35px -100px 0;
}

.header_table li a .dropdown-menu {
    color: #D4AF37;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-left: 3px;
}

/* Removes Margin from last link */
.last_link:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

/* Hero Image */
.hero-image_container {
    border: 2px solid magenta;
    position: relative;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    max-width: 100%;
    /* min-width: 375px; */
}

/* Hero Company Name */
.hero-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

/* Hero Header Text */
h1 {
    /* border: 2px solid green; */
    font-family: 'dampfplatz_solidblack';
    font-size: 10rem;
    /* margin-bottom: 1em; this will scale based on font size [43:00]*/
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    /* -webkit-text-stroke: 4px #D4AF37; */
    /* text-shadow: -1px 0 #D4AF37, 0 5px #D4AF37, 1px 0 #D4AF37, 0 -1px #D4AF37; */
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 3.75px #D4AF37;
}

/* Hero Desctiption Text */
h3 {
    /* border: 2px solid yellow; */
    font-family: 'Arapey';
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: rgba(217, 184, 184, 0.25);
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 51%;
    width: 731px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 64%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    /* margin-top: 1rem; */
}

/* Main Shopping Section */
.store-container {
    margin: auto;
}

/* Section Header Text */
h2 {
    /* Todo: Gold Effect vertical, padding */
    font-family: Dampfplatz Solid;
    font-size: 5rem;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1.5rem 0 2.5rem 0;
    margin: 25px 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #55382B, #D7BA70, #55382B);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

/* New Dope Shit Store Section */
.nds-Store_container {
    width: 92%;
    margin: auto;
    /* border: 2px solid aqua; */
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 8em;
}

/* Store Grid */
.basic-grid {
    display: grid;
    gap: 4em;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 2fr));
}

/* Store Product */
.product {
    border: 2px solid rgba(218, 165, 32, 0.262);
    /* padding-top: 1rem; */
}

.product>h4 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.productSVG {
    width: 100%;
}

/* Price of Product */
mark {
    background-color: #141414;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

/* Store Products Text */
h4 {
    font-family: Arapey;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: #D4AF37;
}

/* MEDIA QUERIS */

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {

    .hamburger,
    .nav-links {
        display: none;
    }

    .hero-image_container-mobile {
        display: none;
    }

    .header_table {
        /* visibility: hidden; */
        /* display: inline; */
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .nav-links {
        display: none;
    }

    .header_table {
        display: none;
    }

    .hero-image_container {
        display: none;
    }

    /* Hero Company Name */
    .hero-text {
        position: absolute;
        top: 33.2%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        text-align: center;
    }

    /* Hero Header Text */
    h1 {
        font-size: 9rem;
    }

    /* Hero Desctiption Text */
    h3 {
        font-size: 2.1rem;
        border-radius: 15px;
        width: 450px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 42%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        text-align: center;
        padding: 2px 0;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 3.5rem;
        margin: 8px 0;
    }

    .nds-Store_container {
        width: 75%;
    }

    h4 {
        font-family: Arapey;
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        color: #D4AF37;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a -60px on the class `.header-functionality` is this the issue?

Comment: Tried this and it still kept the small gap at the top

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the gap you are referring to correctly (it's a little hard to tell from the image you provided) just remove the 10px margin in your `.logo` class.

```
    .logo {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto 0 auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    background-color: #141414;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    /* 10px */
    /* font-size: calc(1em + 0.5vw); */
}

body,
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* TODO: FIGURE OUT PROBLEM WITH STICKY NAV BAR! */
/* Navigation Section*/
header {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    top: 0;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 1000;
}

nav {
    background-color: #141414;
    opacity: 0.98;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Hamburger- Mobile Devices */
.line {
    width: 62px;
    height: 11px;
    background: #D4AF37;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
}

/* Hamburger- Top Line */
.line-top {
    top: 28px;
    left: 41px;
}

/* Hamburger- Middle Line */
.line-middle {
    top: 48px;
    left: 41px;
}

/* Hamburger- Bottom Line */
.line-bottom {
    top: 68px;
    left: 41px;
}

/* Dopematik Logo */
.logo {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto 0 auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Header Functionality (Search & Cart SVG) */
.header_functionality {
    text-align: right;
    width: 95vw;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: -60px;
}

/* Shopping Cart SVG */
.shoppingCartSvg {
    padding-left: 35px;
}

/* Navigation Links: Mobile*/
.nav-links {
    border: 2px solid green;
    text-align: center;
    height: 85vh;
}

.nav-links li {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

.nav-links a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #CDB04E;
    font-size: 6rem;
}

.nav-links a:hover {
    color: whitesmoke;
}

/* Navigation Links: Desktop */
.header_table {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.header_table ul {
    font-size: 3.2rem;
    list-style: none;
    /* margin: 5px 0; */
}

.header_table li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.header_table li a {
    font-family: 'Arapey';
    color: #D4AF37;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 5px 35px -100px 0;
}

.header_table li a .dropdown-menu {
    color: #D4AF37;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-left: 3px;
}

/* Removes Margin from last link */
.last_link:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <!-- Navigation: Mobile -->
            <div class="hamburger">
                <div class="line line-top"></div>
                <div class="line line-middle"></div>
                <div class="line line-bottom"></div>
            </div>
            <img class="logo" src="../icons/SVG/logo.svg" alt="Dopematik Logo">
            <div class="header_functionality">
                <img style="cursor: pointer;" class="searchSvg" src="../icons/SVG/search.svg" alt="Search Button">
                <img style="cursor: pointer;" class="shoppingCartSvg" src="../icons/SVG/shoppingCart.svg"
                    alt="Shopping Cart Button">
            </div>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Navigation: Deskop -->
            <div class="header_table">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About<mark class="dropdown-menu">&#9660;</mark></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Shop<mark class="dropdown-menu">&#9660;</mark></a></li>
                    <li><a class="last_link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: How can I upload a new picture i tried this solution and it didnt fix the gap but i took a better screen shot to see if it will show problem better

Comment: The new screen shot is with the following code you suggested to switch                    
 .logo {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}

Comment: It's hard to reproduce your problem as the code you provided doesn't match that of your screenshot, but try adding " min-height: 100vh; " to your html/body in your CSS.

Comment: I can add more of my code to match the screen shot my bad, for now i did a quick fix and it seemed to work i just added nav { margin-top: -4.6px; } and it seemed to cover up the problem i was talking about for now

Answer (score 0):

I think a rough solution to this is to position the SVG files to absolute, position absolute will not leave any gap where it would have been. The position of the line on the header is based on parent position, thus

```
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 1rem;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Position the header_functionality to position relative because position relative places an element relative to its current position without changing the layout around it.

Comment: Tried this and all it did was move logo from center to the left of screen. and i set header_functionality { position:relative;} if thats what you meant